# How to add a library to to my Google App Engine project?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In response to [this bug at Google](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log&groupby=&sort=&id=2749) I am planning to replace the webob library with the newest release, WebOb version 1.2.3, which is rumored to fix the bug. I have downloaded the project from their website, and just adding it to the project root does not fix the problem. The folder with the downloaded project is named "WebOb-1.2.3"

What needs to be done in App.yaml to include this newest version that i upload to the server?

I am running python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you just copy the folder (e.g. /webob) to the root of your application directory, and as the version is not supported directly as yet don't include it in the app.yaml.